# Sending HTTP POST request via HttpURLConnection in Java doesn't work

Tags: java, php, html

I'd like to send some data to one my test-page, and receive page which was executed by server.
My current result =  server is returning nothing.
Used HTML form:

```
<form action = "s.php" method = "post">
        <input type = "text" name = "test" />
        <input type = "submit" />
    </form>
```

S.php - script which should process data from previously mentioned form:

```
 <? echo $_POST["test"] ?>
```

So I want to receive source code with value of "test" text field.
Java code for this:

```
package nettests;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

class NetTests
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

       URL targetURL = new URL("http://lerain.tode.cz/s.php");
       HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)targetURL.openConnection();
       //data send via POST request
       String data = "test=someData";
       conn.setDoOutput(true);
       conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
       conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
       conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "UTF-8");
       conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(
        data.length()));

       conn.setUseCaches(false);
       try(OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
                                conn.getOutputStream()))
       {
            out.write(data);
       } 

       //reading code after POST request (here I want to have value from "test" field
       try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(        
        conn.getInputStream())))
       {
           String currentLine;
           while((currentLine = in.readLine()) != null)
           {
               System.out.println(currentLine);
           }
       }


 }
 }
```

Can anybody help?
Thanks
(sorry for bad English, not my native :) )

EDIT: solved

Comment: It's not printing anything or is throwing exception?

Comment: Code works without errors, only server is ignoring my request :(

Comment: Then check that your `php` script is actually doing what it should be doing. Try doing some logging.

Comment: I've checked it already. Through browser, it works fine (server echoes value passed to "test" text field).

Comment: Have you checked your server logs to see if PHP is throwing anything up? Any errors from PHP will be logged. I'd start there and post the error logs if you find anything.

Comment: I've checked everything with PHP, it seems something is wrong is in my Java code :(

Comment: I tried running the whole thing and it works as expected: `someData` is printed to the screen. I had to change the URL though, the one in the code gives a 403 error.

Comment: Uaa, now it works!! Don't know why, I didn't change anything (as I can remember). Thanks a lot :) (I was trying it for 3 hours)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, I am trying to build something similar. @Benji is the form and the PHP script all in s.php or do you have a separate html file which posts to s.php?

Comment: @Imre Yes, this code now should not work, because I removed s.php from server specified in code = targetURL is not existing URL. And .html file was there only for decoration purposes =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks William,

Updating the answer for everyone's reference:

As per William's answer:

Switch

> urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" +
>   queryString.length());

to

> ((HttpURLConnection)
>   urlConnection).setFixedLengthStreamingMode(queryString.length());

That resolved the issue.

Comment: What was the solution? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I switched  

`urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + queryString.length());`

to

`((HttpURLConnection) urlConnection).setFixedLengthStreamingMode(queryString.length());`  

That resolved the issue.

Comment: Glad.. it helped you @mehdi